# How to get changes from an array or a collection

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

i have some values (i can put them in an array or a collection) like

```
original = "1", "2", "3", "4", "5, "6", "7", "8", "9"
```

The user can do changes on this items. The user can delete some or add new ones:

```
modified = "2", "3", "4", "6", "10", "11"
```

The user has added "10" and "11" in this sample and deleted "1", "5", "7", "8" and "9".

How can i get these changes from my array or collection. I need a resultset of deleted items with "1", "5", "8", "9" and another one of added items "10" and "11". How can i get these changes?

Comment: Do you need to remember intermediate changes, or just the diff between the current state and the original state?

Comment: Try `Union`, `Intersect`, and `Difference` of sets. You should be able to google all of those and get results in C#.

Comment: @mbeckish: No i dont need intermediate changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method:

```
var added = modified.Except(original);    // "10", "11"
var removed = original.Except(modified);  // "1", "5", "7", "8", "9"
```

But you might want to look at using an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead in case you need to react to the modifications as they happen.

Comment: hmm, what if modified and the original is the same collection ?

Comment: @Selman22, in that case original could be stored/cached earlier, in OriginalOriginal :P

Comment: @Habib / *Selman22* or use an `ObservableCollection<T>` (or other `INotifyCollectionChanged`) as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead and subscribe to its `CollectionChanged` event. There are `Add` and `Remove` actions (among others) that are passed to you in the event handler and you can take a decision based on that.

```
var original = new ObservableCollection<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5, "6", "7", "8", "9" };

original.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => {
  if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add) {
    //Store or do something with added items in e.NewItems.
  } 
  else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove {
    //store or do something with removed items in e.OldItems
  }
};

original.Add("15");
original.RemoveAt(3);
```

The advantage over the other solution is that in case you're dealing with large collections you're not wasting memory on holding the original as well. You can work with only one collection.

Comment: I'd say both solutions apply to different situations.  This solution is better for reacting to each change, but not as good for getting the set of differences between the original and current states.

Comment: @Gusman: OP's might be a naive example, indeed. Doesn't hurt him to know about it, though. Maybe he's not really storing strings in that collection.

Comment: Thanks, but i am not able to determine when someone is adding or deleting single items. I get onLoad a set of items, and after the changes are made, the control returns the modified set.

Comment: +1 It may not be exactly what OP was looking for, but I imagine it would help many people searching for a solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: My thoughts exactly. +1s for everybody!

Comment: @MarcelN. I'm not saying it's wrong nor it's not good to know how to do it, but to what the user asked is a really big waste of resources, it's like using Reflection to take the value of a public variable... nice to know but a waste of resources :)